# Is it possible to keep added ssh keys in ssh-agent after reboot? (using keychain)

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent, keychain

Is it possible to keep added ssh keys in ssh-agent after reboot?

As I figure out we use keychain to make ssh-agent keep running between logins, Am I right? so, is there anyway to keeps password somewhere safe with keychain and feed them automatically to key-add?

What about using a key without password? is there any different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to keep added ssh keys in ssh-agent after reboot?

No way to keep them over reboot, because RAM is not persistent over reboots. You can put the `ssh-add your_key` into your `~/.bash_profile` to make sure they are added.

Or use `gnome-keyring` or `seahorse`, which where you can store both keys and passphrases.